# How to limit http request number per second on Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, urllib2

How can I write a code to implement the function of limiting http request number per second with python?

For example, I specify 100 request number for the python script, then the script will just send 100 url to the server per second.

I searched out this link: [Limiting number of HTTP requests per second on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098711/limiting-number-of-http-requests-per-second-on-python). However, I did not get it from this page.

Comment: PS: I'm using Python 2.7, so the library for Python 3+ does NOT work for me. Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code? Do you use threads etc, ... ?

Comment: I have no code now. I hope to get the solution then write code. Of course, I can use threads, queue, etc...

Comment: Why not simply do a time.sleep() between requests?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one request at the same time you could just do it with time.sleep(1).

```
import requests
import time

r = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
print(r)
time.sleep(1)
r = requests.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
print(r)
time.sleep(1)
```